# Windows forms binding to test box from SQL query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm sure this is dead simple but cant seem to get it work.

I have the following code that I use to currently update a Windows Form combo box with a value returned from a SQL query.

I now need to do the same thing, i.e. return the server name from the SQL query but instead of populating a combo box I need to populate a label.

```
//Create new sql connection
                SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection();
                //to refresh connection string each time else it will use previous connection string
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
                db.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ToolboxDatabase"].ToString();
//Check connection string has update has worked
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select @@Server AS ServerName", db);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                cmbTestValue.DataSource = dt;
                cmbTestValue.DisplayMember = "ServerName";
```

Please help

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select @@Server AS ServerName", db);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Label1.Text = dt.Rows[0]["ServerName"].ToString();
```